# Nested BooleanQuery?

Tags: lucene

I'm using a BooleanQuery to combine several queries. I find that if I add a BooleanQuery to the BooleanQuery, then no result is returned. The added BooleanQuery is a MUST_NOT one, like -city_id:100.

But as lucene's spec says, BooleanQuery could be nested, which I think means it's okay to add such BooleanQuery. Now I have to get all clauses from the BooleanQuery to be added, and then add them to the container BooleanQuery one by one.

I'm a bit confused. Anybody could help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucene does not support unary NOT operator. But you can get results for such query by ANDing it with [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html).

Comment: Ah, it seems work. Thanks. But isn't this confusing? I add BooleanQuery to BooleanQuery, and still I need to check whether the query to be added has AND some query.
Also, does ANDing MatchAllDocsQuery in this case undermine the performance?

Comment: You can read about the boolean query idiosyncracies on this thread. http://search-lucene.com/m/8x64lENo571/  Essentially, NOT is just suppresses documents. You need another positive set for it to work with.

I don't know the details of implementation of MatchAllDocsQuery, but gettig all docs should be fast enough. The addtional ANDing operation should be fast as well as internally it operations on a bitset.

Comment: Apologies for the broken sentences in the previous comment.