# not query in lucene

Tags: indexing, lucene

i need to do not queries on my lucene index. Lucene currently allows not only when we have two or more terms in the query:

So I can do something like:

```
country:canada not sweden
```

but I can't run a query like:

```
country:not sweden
```

Could you please let me know if there is some efficient solution for this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 57):

A very late reply, but it might be useful for somebody else later:

```
*:* AND NOT country:sweden
```

IF I'm not mistaken this should do a logical "AND" with all documents and the documents with a country that is different from "sweden".

Comment: I was struggling because the lucene StandardQueryParser was not correctly parsing this "-country:sweden". Apparently the parser converted it to "country:sweden". This comment clarified a common use case for me.

Answer (score 15):

Try with the following query in the search box:

```
NOT message:"warning"
```

**message** being the search field

Comment: Important: It is case sensitive

Comment: Important: “NOT” and field name are case sensitive. Field value is not.

Answer (score 5):

Please check answer for similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825597/nested-booleanquery). The solution is to use [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that this is not possible using the standard Lucene.

Lucene does not allow `NOT` queries as a single term for the same reason it does not allow prefix queries - to perform either, the engine would have to look through each document to ascertain whether the document is/is not a hit. It has to look through each document because it cannot use the search term as the key to look up documents in the inverted index (used to store the indexed documents).

To take your case as an example:

> To search for `not sweden`, the simplest (and possibly most efficient) approach would be to search for `sweden` and then "invert" the result set to return all documents that are not in that result set. Doing this would require finding all the required (ie. not in the result set) documents in the index, but without a key to look them up by. This would be done by iterating over the documents in the index - a task it is not optimised for, and hence speed would suffer.

If you really need this functionality, you could maintain your own list of items when indexing, so that a `not sweden` search becomes a `sweden` search using Lucene, followed by an inversion of the results using your set of items.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see what you are trying to do.

You can use it as a query refinement since there are no unary Boolean operators in Lucene. Despite the answers above, I believe this is a better and most forward approach (**note the space before the wildcard**):

```
&query= *&qf=-country:Canada
```